# Timing a recursive iteration through a nested object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, iteration, for-in-loop

I have an object with the following structure.

```
var obj = {
        "a":{"content": [/*elements*/]},
        "b":{
            "d":{
                "g":{"content":[/*elements*/]},
                "h":{
                    "j":{"content":[/*elements*/]},
                    "k":{"content":[/*elements*/]}
                },
                "i":{
                    "l":{"content":[/*elements*/]}
                }
            },
            "e":{"content":[/*elements*/]},
            "f":{"content":[/*elements*/]}
        },
        "c":{"content":[/*elements*/]},
        /* Object goes on with different levels of nesting*/
    };
```

The format of the nested object exhibits a unique behavior - 
Each nested object either has **1.** one property named `"content"` whose
value is a 1-D array of elements, or **2.** Different levels nested objects 
whose properties finally narrow down to (1) above.

I have a recursive function to search the `content` arrays of the entire obj as follows:

```
function search(index) {
    for(var key in index) {
            var current = index[key];
            var cLength = Object.keys(current).length;

            if(cLength > 1 ) {
                search(current);
            } else {
             if (index[key]["content"] == undefined) {
                    search(current);
                } else { 
                    contentsArray = index[key]["content"];
                    // Search Contents Array
                }
            }
    }
}

search(obj);
```

The actual obj is a deeply nested object with quite a lot of data entries.
I want to run benchmark tests to get the average time it would
take to search for an element in the `"contents"` array any of the nested objects. My question is - How do I recognize 
last `for...in` loop of the parent object `obj` while recursively looping through it? (To record the finish time) Is there a better way to time the
execution of such a function?

I've tried pushing the times at which a `for loop` finishes looping through the `"contents"` array (for each nested object) to a global `execTime` array, then using a `setTimeout` function outside of the search function to get the difference between the `max` and `min` values in `execTime` since I'm not sure when the recursive search function stops executing.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, why not just do `console.time("recursion"); search(obj); console.timeEnd("recursion");`? You can swap out `console.time` for other methods to get the timing, if you wish but basically, just measure when the initial call to `search` starts and finishes.

Comment: @vlaz - good suggestion. Here's a link to a working example: https://leetcode.com/playground/dFD5Dgec

Answer (score 1):

@VLAZ's comment proved quite useful: I've settled to using the following to run the benchmark tests (Still haven't figured out 
a *in-code solution, but this gets the job done)

```
console.time("recursion"); 
search(obj); 
console.timeEnd("recursion");
```

Heres a working [demo](https://leetcode.com/playground/dFD5Dgec)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your search function return the total execution time that you can add back up all the way to the initial `search` call.

When the search function hits the `return`, that will be your last recursive call. For example, on the last call `cLength` will be zero, meaning further search is not needed and the `else` will execute hitting the `return` after.This will keep happening all the way to the initial `search` call.

Comment: note that each recursive call will have it's own return statement. Also, there isn't a time that cLength will be equal to zero (always `1`or `>1`) since all the nested objects have at least one property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the User Timing API, in the browser

```js
function doStuff() {
  // long running
}

performance.mark('start-token');
doStuff();
performance.mark('end-token');
performance.measure('time', 'start-token', 'end-token');

console.log('time: ', performance.getEntriesByType("measure")[0].duration);
performance.clearMarks();
performance.clearMeasures();
```